# Selecting element with id attribute data bound via Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, knockout.js

Why is this element undefined when I try to select the element using `jQuery`:

```
    <ul data-bind="attr: {id: panelId}"></ul>
```

`panelId` is defined as a property in `Knockoutjs` ViewModel:

```
    var VM = function () {
       var self = this,
           date = new Date();
       self.panelId = "panel-" + date.getTime();

       $("#"+self.panelId).doSomthing(); // element is undefined
    }
```

Inspecting the page in Chrome developer tool, I can see the id is assigned like so

```
    <ul data-bind ... id="panel-1368039734501"</ul>
```

The `panelId` property doesn't have to be `observable`. But I tried to make it observable but same result.

Anyone?

Comment: Where do you call the `ko.applyBindings`? Because you should do it **before** you try to call `$("#"+self.panelId).doSomthing()`...

Comment: `ko.applyBindings(new VM())` is called inside ready handler: `$(function(){ ko.applyBindings(new VM());})`.

Comment: If you are trying to perform an action on the element, sounds like a perfect candidate for a custom binding handler.

Comment: I just want to be able to select that element using `jQuery` inside ViewModel: `console.log($("#"+self.panelId));` says undefined. `console.log(self.panel)` prints the value, which is the value assigned to the element's id attr. when inspecting the element using developer tool.

Comment: With your current script, the selector would only execute once on initialization. The id wouldn't be changed at that point. Execute the selector outside of your viewmodel, like after you apply bindings in the ready function.

Comment: I need to reference the element inside my ViewModel and perform some action. You are right - the id hasn't got its value at the time I am referencing the element. HOW TO SOLVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the ID attribute is only applied in the `ko.applyBindings` call, but you try to find the element by ID before that.

To avoid that, do something like this:

```
var VM = function () {
   var self = this,
       date = new Date();
   self.panelId = "panel-" + date.getTime();
}

var vm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm); // Adds the ID attribute

$("#"+vm.panelId).doSomething(); // This needs to be after ko.applyBindings
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I figured it out after two hours of struggling. I have a main ViewModel that has an `obsservableArray()` of VM objects. I wrote a function inside main ViewModel that traverses the `observableArray()` of VMs and for each of them calls `$("#"+vm.panelId)`. I call this function like so: `var mainVM = new ManinVM` and then `ko.applyBinding(mainVM)` and then as you suggest in your answer `mainVM.theFuncImentioned();`